# How can I link the source code .org file when exporting it?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an .org file in which I want to insert the source code that generated the web page when is exported to HTML, this is, the .org file itself, but when I do it's changed to the .html file. How can I achieve this?

This is the code of the link:

```
[[./documentation.org][Download .org source file]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the org-mode manual: [Links in HTML export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Links-in-HTML-export.html#Links-in-HTML-export), I only had to add to my init.el file the following sentence

```lisp
(setq org-html-link-org-files-as-html nil)
```